# Does $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ be the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

It is known that
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}$$
if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.

Hence, **if it is known that $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$**, then it follows that
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}$$
since we can compute
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{2n^2/\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot\Bigg(\gcd\bigg(1,\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n}\bigg)\Bigg)^2.$$

But since $n^2 \nmid \sigma(n^2)$, then $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$ implies that
$$n\cdot{\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))\cdot\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\Bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\Bigg)^2=n^2$$
from which we obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}=n=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}.$$

---

**Edit: October 5, 2021 - 1:56 PM Manila time** I have just found a gap in the proof.  If $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, then it does not follow from $n^2 \nmid \sigma(n^2)$ that $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = n$.  (In fact, since $\sigma(n^2) = cn$ for some $c > (8/5)n$, then $c$, <s>which is just a proper divisor of $n$</s>, must be large.)  We then have
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = cn$$
which contradicts
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = n$$
to several orders of magnitude.

---

(We can then derive the estimates
$$\frac{8n}{5} < q^k < 2n$$
by considering either the resulting abundancy index of $q^k$ or that of $n^2$.)
Note that we then have
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}=n=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
under the assumption that $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$.

Here is my question:

> Does $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried checking for examples of numbers $n$ satisfying the divisibility constraint
$$n \mid \sigma(n^2)$$
using a Pari-GP script, via [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA10lEwNAADHYXMNA0N3_wUjeLM9NxEjYo4I02dCk0FW1sFA02dgqLMvBKNCp20xOQSkEZNIAAAZksS2Q==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==):

```
for(x=2, 1000000, if((Mod(sigma(x^2),x) == 0),print(x,factor(x))))
```

Here is the output:

```
39[3, 1; 13, 1]
793[13, 1; 61, 1]
2379[3, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1]
7137[3, 2; 13, 1; 61, 1]
13167[3, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 19, 1]
76921[13, 1; 61, 1; 97, 1]
78507[3, 2; 11, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1]
230763[3, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1; 97, 1]
238887[3, 2; 11, 1; 19, 1; 127, 1]
549549[3, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1]
692289[3, 2; 13, 1; 61, 1; 97, 1]
863577[3, 2; 11, 2; 13, 1; 61, 1]
```

Note that all of the known examples are **odd**.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck!**

Comment: The answer is yes because there are no odd perfect numbers.

Comment: @markvs: Are you 100% sure that there are no odd perfect numbers?  =)

Comment: Yes, $100\%$ sure.

Comment: Do you have a proof for that assertion, @markvs?

Comment: This assertion cannot be formally proved at the time but so is the opposite.  I also cannot prove by myself that $E=mc^2$, the Fermat's last theorem, and many other things. It does not mean that I am not $100\%$ sure these are true.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A232354